# Error with Facebook login with parse (swift 2)

Tags: parse-platform, authentication, swift2, facebook-login

Ive been following the tutorial for logging in using Facebook. My code (below) gives no errors until I attempt to run it. When i run the code in the simulator it compiles "Successfully". When i click on the button however i get the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error. I have checked to make sure that my button is linked properly and have even restarted the project but i still get the same error. How can this be fixed?

p.s. 
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY1No.png)

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse
    import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_photos"]

        if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {

            print("connected already")

        } else {

            PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let user = user {
                    if user.isNew {
                        print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    } else {
                        print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something wrong:

```
 if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {

        print("connected already")
```

Access Token should be used in different way:

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
    // logged in

} else {

}
```

This should work:

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_photos"]

    if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        // logged in

        print("Logged In")

    } else {
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let user = user {
                    if user.isNew {
                        print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    } else {
                        print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```